# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' while getting location API from openweathermap

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i was trying out a tutorial on Flutter course (https://www.udemy.com/share/101WB6/) in which location data is retreived from API call and the error shows up while decoding the data,
i tried changing the data types of the variables but still the error persists.
the error message is:

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///C:/Users/saleem/StudioProjects/Clima/lib/main.dart:9:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _LocationScreenState.updateUI (package:clima/screens/location_screen.dart:25:30)
#1      _LocationScreenState.initState (package:clima/screens/location_screen.dart:21:5)
#2      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
#3      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
...     Normal element mounting (132 frames)
```

i tried changing the data types of variables to be all String and all var, iam really to the programming scene
i will attach the dart code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants.dart';

class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LocationScreen({this.locationWeather});
  final locationWeather;

  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  double temperature;
  int condition;
  String cityName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.locationWeather);
    updateUI(widget.locationWeather);
  }

  void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
    temperature = weatherData['main']['temp'];
    condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
    cityName = weatherData['name'];
  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the API output

```
I/flutter (14299): "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":139.01,\"lat\":35.02},\"weather\":[{\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01n\"}],\"base\":\"stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":285.514,\"pressure\":1013.75,\"humidity\":100,\"temp_min\":285.514,\"temp_max\":285.514,\"sea_level\":1023.22,\"grnd_level\":1013.75},\"wind\":{\"speed\":5.52,\"deg\":311},\"clouds\":{\"all\":0},\"dt\":1485792967,\"sys\":{\"message\":0.0025,\"country\":\"JP\",\"sunrise\":1485726240,\"sunset\":1485763863},\"id\":1907296,\"name\":\"Tawarano\",\"cod\":200}"
```

> **The issue is solved i had used jsonEncode instead of jsonDecode**

Comment: Please add the output of the api, it'd make it easier to help.

Comment: I/flutter (14299): "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":139.01,\"lat\":35.02},\"weather\":[{\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01n\"}],\"base\":\"stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":285.514,\"pressure\":1013.75,\"humidity\":100,\"temp_min\":285.514,\"temp_max\":285.514,\"sea_level\":1023.22,\"grnd_level\":1013.75},\"wind\":{\"speed\":5.52,\"deg\":311},\"clouds\":{\"all\":0},\"dt\":1485792967,\"sys\":{\"message\":0.0025,\"country\":\"JP\",\"sunrise\":1485726240,\"sunset\":1485763863},\"id\":1907296,\"name\":\"Tawarano\",\"cod\":200}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API output is a string.

Firstly **import 'dart:convert';**

And wrap your API output in **jsonDecode( API_OUTPUT )**.

That'll make it into a json object whose contents can then be accessed in the way that you are doing.

Comment: cityName = weatherData['name'].toString();  i tried this but no effect, jsonDecode(weatherData)??

Answer (score 0):

A link to the tutorial would have been nice. I guess it is

```
condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
```

which should be

```
condition = weatherData['weather']['0']['id'];
```

Comment: https://www.udemy.com/share/101WB6/ no that did not work

Answer (score 0):

int condition => String condition;
or parse line 30 to int

Comment: not working i tried commentig the lines where i decoded the json and changing variable types to String